# ApplicationUser object for Facebook or other Social Media Logins in Ap.net Core

Tags: asp.net, facebook, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

How can we access the properties of the ApplicationUser from the Account Controller in. While creating a an ApplicationUser object with User, object reference set to null error occurs.The example code is

```
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");
            return View(nameof(Login));
        }
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login.
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(5, "User logged in with {Name} provider.", info.LoginProvider);

            //I want to access the ApplicationUser Properites here

            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(SendCode), new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return View("Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user does not have an account, then ask the user to create an account.
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = email });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to access the ApplicationUser like this...

```
//I want to access the ApplicationUser Properites here
var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey);
```

Comment: it returns null but, it is not handled..